# How to send an empty response with Http Status 202 from Jax-Ws WebMethod

Tags: java, web-services, soap, response, axis

i'm trying to implement an answer like this (taken from SoapUI RAW):

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 15:44:14 GMT
```

In my Axis WebService that has a void webmethod.

I've added an HandlerChain to manipulate the soapresponse and tried something like that:

```
            SOAPMessage response = context.getMessage(); 
            SOAPPart sp = response.getSOAPPart (); 
            SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope ();
            response.getSOAPBody().removeContents();
            response.getSOAPHeader().removeContents();
            response.getSOAPPart().removeAllMimeHeaders();
            env.removeContents();
            context.getMessage().removeAllAttachments();
            response.getMimeHeaders().removeAllHeaders();
```

But i have an empty envelope tag with an HTTP 200.

Can anybody show me how to do that?
I've also added a @Oneway Annotation to my webmethod, but it didn't helped...

thanks in advance!